# WebView with shouldOverrideUrlLoading and baseURL

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView on my application and some links which are URL adresses.
Some of them don't have the baseURL, only something like "/abc/abc"

I would like to set the baseURL for all the links starting with "/".
I have tryed this:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.EditorialWebView);
wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", editorialBoard, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
if (url.startsWith("/")) 
    {
wv.loadUrl("http://www.mdpi.com"+url);
}  
return true;
}                      
});
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("/")) {
      Uri u = Uri.fromParts("http://www.domain.com", url, "");
      view.loadUrl(u);
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Please let me know if it works for you as I am unable to test it at the moment.